# How to use multiple generated bootstrap timepicker fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

```
<table class="table table-bordered right-to-left grade_set_tbl ">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" id="timepicker1"    name="period_time_end[]">
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" id="timepicker2"    name="period_time_start[]" >
    </td> 
     <td >
    <i class="fa fa-plus" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="addit('grade_set_tbl');"></i></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

---

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker();
function addit(my_id){
    var rowCount = $('.'+my_id+' tr').length
    $('.'+my_id+' tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('.'+my_id+' tbody>tr:last');

    $('.'+my_id+' tbody>tr:last td:last').empty().html('<i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa fa-remove" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();return false; "></i>');

   }
```

When adding new row , the new row added with the same elements of last one as I want but ,my problem is Timepicker field is not working in all instances . only the first row
[image: this is what happen when cilcking any field]

Comment: You have to initialize the timepicker on the newly added ones.  The first initialize only does those that are found at the time that you do the dom lookup.  OR, you might try cloning with clone(true, true).  The second one makes it a deep clone.  http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker();
function addit(my_id){
    var rowCount = $('.'+my_id+' tr').length
    $('.'+my_id+' tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('.'+my_id+' tbody>tr:last');
    $('.'+my_id+' tbody>tr:last .timepicker').timepicker(); // <-- call timepicker() on new .timepicker
    $('.'+my_id+' tbody>tr:last td:last').empty().html('<i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa fa-remove" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();return false; "></i>');

   }
```

Comment: Prefect :) I used your timepicker call and changed clone(true) into clone()
Thx Taplr , Thx BG101
but I don't understand difference between clone() and clone(true)

Comment: @wizard999: the first param of method clone is **withDataAndEvents**

Comment: **.clone( [withDataAndEvents ] [, deepWithDataAndEvents ] )** the 1st param will copy `events` and `data` of the cloned element, the 2nd will copy all `events` and `data` of the element and all its children. If this worked for you then please mark as correct ;)